# LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file "libboost_json-vc142-mt-gd-x64-1_75.lib"

Tags: c++, json, boost, cmake, clion

I am trying to build my project on Windows.
I compile with Clion. And toolchain for using it is Visual Studio 2019 x64
This is my CmakeList.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.17)
project ("FB_REGULA")
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)

set(Boost_DEBUG 1)
set(Boost_DEBUG ON)
set(Boost_ARCHITECTURE -x64)
set(BOOST_ROOT "c:/repos/libs/boost_1_75_0")
set(BOOST_INCLUDEDIR "c:/repos/libs/boost_1_75_0")
set(BOOST_LIBRARYDIR "C:/repos/libs/boost_1_75_0/lib64-msvc-14.2")
#set(BOOST_ROOT "c:/repos/libs/boost_manual/boost_1_75_0")
#set(BOOST_INCLUDEDIR "c:/repos/libs/boost_manual/boost_1_75_0")
#set(BOOST_LIBRARYDIR "c:/repos/libs/boost_manual/boost_1_75_0/stage/x64/lib")


#[[set(Boost_USE_STATIC_LIBS OFF)
set(Boost_USE_MULTITHREADED ON)
set(Boost_USE_STATIC_RUNTIME OFF)
ADD_DEFINITIONS("-DBOOST_ALL_NO_LIB")]]

find_package(Boost 1.75.0 REQUIRED)
if(Boost_FOUND)
    include_directories(${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS})
endif()

add_library(RegulaLibrary SHARED IMPORTED)
include_directories(RegulaDllDirectory "D:/Husan/projects_work/FB_REGULA/DR_SDK")
```

And my cmake build output :

```
"C:\Program Files\JetBrains\CLion
   2020.3.2\bin\cmake\win\bin\cmake.exe" -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug -G "CodeBlocks - NMake Makefiles" D:\Husan\projects_work\FB_REGULA
   --  _boost_TEST_VERSIONS = <unset>
   --  Boost_USE_MULTITHREADED = "TRUE"
   --  Boost_USE_STATIC_LIBS = "ON"
   --  BOOST_ROOT = "c:/repos/libs/boost_1_75_0"
   --  ENV{BOOST_ROOT} = "C:\repos\libs\boost_1_75_0"
   --  BOOST_INCLUDEDIR = "c:/repos/libs/boost_1_75_0"
   --  ENV{BOOST_INCLUDEDIR} = "C:\repos\libs\boost_1_75_0"
   --  BOOST_LIBRARYDIR = "C:/repos/libs/boost_1_75_0/lib64-msvc-14.2"
   --  ENV{BOOST_LIBRARYDIR} = "C:\repos\libs\boost_1_75_0\lib64-msvc-14.2"
   --  location of version.hpp: C:/repos/libs/boost_1_75_0/boost/version.hpp
   --  Boost_VERSION = "1.75.0"
   --  Boost_VERSION_STRING = "1.75.0"
   --  Boost_VERSION_MACRO = "107500"
   --  Boost_VERSION_MAJOR = "1"
   --  Boost_VERSION_MINOR = "75"
   --  Boost_VERSION_PATCH = "0"
   --  Boost_VERSION_COUNT = "3"
   --  Boost_LIB_PREFIX = "lib"
   --  Boost_NAMESPACE = "boost"
   -- _boost_COMPILER = "-vc142;-vc141;-vc140" (guessed)
   --  _boost_MULTITHREADED = "-mt"
   --  _boost_ARCHITECTURE_TAG = "-x64" (user-specified via Boost_ARCHITECTURE)
   --  _boost_RELEASE_ABI_TAG = "-"
   --  _boost_DEBUG_ABI_TAG = "-gd"
   --  _boost_LIBRARY_SEARCH_DIRS_RELEASE = "C:/repos/libs/boost_1_75_0/lib64-msvc-14.2;NO_DEFAULT_PATH;NO_CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH"
   --  _boost_LIBRARY_SEARCH_DIRS_DEBUG = "C:/repos/libs/boost_1_75_0/lib64-msvc-14.2;NO_DEFAULT_PATH;NO_CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH"
   -- Configuring done
   -- Generating done
   -- Build files have been written to: D:/Husan/projects_work/FB_REGULA/cmake-build-debug-visual-studio-x64
```

Please someone who can solve this is issue please answer my question.

Comment: I don't see anywhere that you're linking the body libraries to your target?

Comment: I  using #include <boost/json.hpp>

Comment: thats including, not linking

Comment: I'm new in C++ there for can you explain more detailed

Comment: @Husan including and linking are rather basic different things - I think you need to read some books or basic tutorials e,g, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list